# LiveData not Updating Dialog ui After ReOpen

Tags: android, kotlin

when open the dialog first time and make a request .. the live data observer updating my ui .. but when close it and open it again ... the observer not updating my ui .. although it showing a toast

Dialog

```
     class ChooseTerritoryDialog(
private var activity: AppCompatActivity,
private var listener: OnSelectTerritory,
private val accountId: Int
```

) : BaseDialog(activity), ChooseTerritoryAdapter.OnTerritoryItem {

```
lateinit var binding: SearchListLayoutBinding
lateinit var adapter: ChooseTerritoryAdapter
lateinit var viewModel: ChooseTerritoryViewModel

var list: ArrayList<ListEntity>? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = viewDataBinding!!
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(activity)[ChooseTerritoryViewModel::class.java]


    binding.search.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {


            if (charSequence.isNotEmpty()) {

            } else {

            }


        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {}
    })
    binding.close.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { dismiss() })
    viewModel.getTerritories(accountId)

    setObservers()
}
```

Observers

```
fun setObservers() {


    viewModel.state.observeOnce(activity , Observer {
        binding.search.setText("test")
        binding.progress.isVisible = it == Status.Loading
        when (it) {
            is Status.Loading -> {
            }
            is Status.Success<*> -> {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val response = it.data as BaseResponse<ArrayList<TerritoryItem>>
                adapter = ChooseTerritoryAdapter(response.data!!, this)
                binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
            }

            is Status.Error -> {
                Toast.makeText(activity, it.message!!, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })



}
```

Comment: when you set the items in the adapter you execute the method notifyDataSetChanged()? try this

Comment: yes i do ... the problem is all ui not update

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling functions that are updating UI inside of `onCreate()`. However this is Fragment. These methods should be called inside of `onViewCreated()`. That's why your Toast is showing, but the UI can't be updated.

Another potential problem is in these 2 lines:

```
viewModel.getTerritories(accountId)
setObservers()
```

Switch order. First subscribe and then fetch.